# How to reduce time in a Java execution program?

Tags: java, apache-poi, pdfbox

I'm kind of new in this theme, I want to reduce time in a program execution, I can not post any of the code for politics with the client, but I will try to be the most detailed as I can.

I have this program on Java and uses the next libraries:

1. pdfbox 1.8.2
2. poi 3.7

and the common ones, java util, io, regex, and swing.

The inputs are:
 1. "mom PDF" file
 2. excel original file

The outputs:

1. childs pdf files
2. An output excel with the information

This program takes information from a pdf file and put into an excel file. The pdf file could have hundreds of pages. What does the program do is read the *"mom PDF"* file search for a *"the word"* and if this word is in that page it creates a "child pdf" file with that only page, extracts the information required, open the excel file write down the information extracted from that page, close the excel file and close the *"child pdf"*. this action repeats the numbers of times as the regex finds *"the word"* in the *"mom PDF"* .The program is structured in 3 blocks.

- *The setting block* . When I prepare the file directions and initialize them
- *The extraction block*. When the program reads the pdf file and search for the information that is needed to be in the excel file
- *The excel block*. When the program prints the information extracted
  from the PDF into the excel file.

An attempt to made shorter the time, was to separate the three blocks of code and only have a main class and do the calls from there to the methods of the blocks, It worked at first but it did not after few testing. The time of execution takes too long, I want to know if there is a way to made it shorter.

A previous version of the program was to create from a scratch the excel file were the information is placed, but I need to take an input file because it have an specific format that need to be followed. This previous version was faster.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Given the scarce information you provided, it is next to impossible to make qualified guesses. Have you done some tests with analysis tools, e.g. jvisualvm? Where is the time consumed? In some library calls? Or is the performance problem located you your code?

Comment: How many child files will you produce? How many times does "the word" occur in `mom.pdf`? How long does it take to write each PDF?

Comment: [apache poi version 3.7](https://poi.apache.org/changes.html#3.7) is 7 years old and many changings were made until current stable version `3.16`. Why using such an old piece of software?

Comment: PDFBox 1.8.2 is from 2013 and contains a known security risk. Are you working for Experian?

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments, I solved it by doing a new excel file instead of doing one already done, it reduced the time from 1 hour to 8 minutes.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Thanks for the information, I will report that security risk, And no I'm not working for Experian

Answer (score 1):

Usually it is one piece of code that is causing most of the performance problems. In industry the established practice is to just remove that one bottleneck before even deciding whether next profiling iteration is needed. Save yourself alot of trouble by not GUESSING about what might be the sub optimal part of your code and instead LOOKING at what is causing the slowdown. Usually people are unable to guess by looking at code. All it takes is to run visualvm (part of standard JDK) in sampler mode, making one snapshot and then looking at stack trace. After you identified that one method, the laziest approach is to just cache data (for example results of parsing child pdfs might be stored in hashmap)